# MongoDB Increment or Upsert

Tags: mongodb

Given the following document structure:

```
{
         '_id': ObjectId("559943fcda2485a66285576e"),
         'user': '70gw3',
         'data': [
            {
              'date': ISODate("2015-06-29T00:00:00.0Z"),
              'clicks': 1,
            },
            {
              'date': ISODate("2015-06-30T00:00:00.0Z"),
              'clicks': 5,
            },
          ]
    }
```

How can I increment the `clicks` value of `2015-06-30` and increase if it doesn't exists [the whole document *OR* the specific date], make it equals to `1`?

Comment: Did you mean `'data': [ {'date': ISODate("2015-06-29T00:00:00.0Z"), 'clicks': 1}, {'date': ISODate("2015-06-30T00:00:00.0Z"), 'clicks': 5,}]`?

Comment: Just updated my question

Comment: OK, but duplicate fields will be dropped in the `date` sub-document. So there will be only one `date` and only one `clicks`.

Comment: Thats exactly what I want, only one count per date. see my updated document please.

Comment: No sure I understand the question, but yes..

Comment: Oh yes! it is an array, sorry my bad.

Comment: What are your limitations? I'm afraid you cannot do that in a single query.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible using a single query. If your data is relatively dense then creating a whole array  filled with zeros and using `inc` is a possible workaround. For time series data it provides one additional benefit. If document is preallocated there is no moving data around when it grows.

Comment: I see. i think my solution will be as follows: I will query for the entry with the `user` id, if it doesnt have a `data.date[my_date_here]` entry, I will `push` it to be 1, otherwise I  will just increment it. sounds reasonable?

Comment: You are very close, I have updated my question, check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to achieve your goal within a single query. But instead you can do the following

```
var exists = db.yourCollection.find(
    {'_id': ObjectId("559943fcda2485a66285576e"), 'data.date': <your date>}
).count()
```

This query will return the number of documents which have the specified `_id` and an object with the specified date in the `data` array. As the `_id` field is unique, you will get at most one result. If such element does not exist in the `data` array, you will not get any result. Thus, you have the following cases:

- exists == 1: There **IS** an element with the specified date
- exists == 0: There **IS NO** element with the specified date

Then this can become your condition:

```
if (exists) {
    db.yourCollection.update({_id: <your id>, 'data.date': <your date>}, {$inc: {'data.$.clicks': 1}})
} else {
    if (db.runCommand({findAndModify: 'yourCollection', query: {_id: <your id>, 'data.date': {$ne: <your date>}}, update: {$push: {data: {date: <your date>, clicks: 1}}}}).value) {
         db.yourCollection.update({_id: <your id>, 'data.date': <your date>}, {$inc: {'data.$.clicks': 1}})
    }
}
```

Comment: But how can I specify an exact date? i just updated my question

Comment: Is the document structure correct? Is `data` supposed to be an array?

Comment: With `if (exists) { ... } else { ... }` you cannot guarantee you won't end up with duplicate entries per date.

Comment: You mean there is a problem in the code or there is a concurrency issue?

Comment: Ok, fixed that with [**`findAndModify`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/). Take a look?

Comment: This sounds amazing, but I dont know how to implement it in laravel5 and I think I will just change the schema structure so that each date will be a separate entry with a count, then I can do `$inc` and upsert incase it doesnt exists.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is that while you need to perform two update operations in order to fulfil the logic there is no need to find and check data in a way.

You have two basic conditions

1. If the element is there then update it
2. If the element is **not** there then add it

The process is basically then two updates. One will succeed and the other will not. No need to check.

Probably the best way to implement this is using the ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations API. This allows both update statements to be sent to the server at the same time, and the response it a single response so there are less trips. But the logic is the same even if you don't use this.

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

// Update the date where it matched
bulk.find({ "user": "70gw3", "data.date": new Date("2015-06-30") })
    .updateOne({ "$inc": { "data.$.clicks": 1 } });

// Push a new element where date does not match
bulk.find({ "user": "70gw3", "data.date": { "$ne": new Date("2015-06-30") } })
    .updateOne({ "$push": { "data": { "date": new Date("2015-06-30"), "clicks": 1 } }});

bulk.execute();
```

In short, out of two update requests sent for any document then only **one** of the operations will actually modify anything. This is because the conditions for testing "date" are the "inverse" of one another, in that you "update" where present, and "create" where the matching element is not present.

Both states cannot exist at the same time, as long as the "create" follows the "update" the logic is sound. So first try to update, and then try to "create" where no match is found.